# Silverlight printing size is too large

Tags: silverlight

I've developed application using Silverlight, and now I need to implement printing, I've used 
PrintDocument class, it looks like this:

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(printDocument_PrintPage);
printDocument.Print("My docuement");
```

But I've faced with problem - it takes much time if there are 20-30 pages, and if I open printer's queue, it shows that printing size is about 1.2GB for 10 printed pages. I've tried to print canvas (800*1000) with only one textblock with simple text like "Test printing".

I'm using Silverlight 5.

Did anybody faced with such problem? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: 1.2GB for 10 printed pages of "Test printing"? Are you sure? Is there nothing else on the pages?

Comment: well... This is my testing markup:
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Height="1000" Width="800">
    <TextBlock Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="200">This is test printing</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
I print it this way:
void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = ++pageCount < 10;
            e.PageVisual = canvas;
        }

Comment: What kind of printer/driver are you using?

Comment: I've tested with HP 2200, 4200 and M3027. It seems that printers with Post Script support use much less memory, but unfortunately, I can not say to all our clients to avoid using their printers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the content to be printed is send as a bitmap instead of a more efficient vector format.

This might be due to the driver. If the driver of the printer is not able to translate the Silverlight graphics into vectors, all it can do is print it as a bitmap.

I tried to [force Silverlight into using Vectors](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/06/11/silverlight-5-vector-and-bitmap-printing-for-reports-and-more) but my printer didn't support PostScript.
So I switched to a printer that does and suddenly it's just kilobytes.

I see only two ways to avoid bitmap printing:

1. Get a PostScript printer or
2. Create a printer friendly document (PDF, Word, text) on the server and allow the client to download and print it by hand.

Comment: You are right, printer with PostScript support works fine, but Isn't it too much to take 120MB/page for bitmap?

Comment: No, at 600DPI a single page can be expected to be that big.

Comment: Seems you are right, there is no good way for silverlight printing using old printer drivers w/o PostScript support.